# Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting '('

Tags: php, pdo, php-parse-error

I get this error when I'm trying to do this:

```
$connBD = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHote;dbname=$dbNom", $dbUtilisateur, $dbMotPasse, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
// Pour lancer les exceptions lorsqu'il y des erreurs PDO.
$connBD -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

I know that T_DOUBLE_ARROW is the token of "=>", but I can't put my finger on my error. Anyone sees it?

Thanks in advance.

Full code before the error occurs:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
<head>
<?php
require ("Include/param_bd.inc");
/*if (!$id_link = mysql_connect($dbHote, $dbUtilisateur, $dbMotPasse)) {
    echo 'Connexion impossible';
    exit;
}
if (!mysql_select_db($dbNom, $id_link)) {
    echo 'BD impossible';
    exit;
}*/
$connBD = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHote;dbname=$dbNom", $dbUtilisateur, $dbMotPasse, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
// Pour lancer les exceptions lorsqu'il y des erreurs PDO.
$connBD -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/GestionDocNew.css" />
<title>Recherche Gestion DOC</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
```

Here's what's in my param_bd.inc file:

```
<?php
// Paramètres de connexion à la base de données
// ==================================================
// Serveur
$dbHote = "ceec-wamp2008";
// Nom d'utilisateur
$dbUtilisateur = "suivisprod";
// Mot de passe
$dbMotPasse = "prodsuivis321";
// Base de données
$dbNom = "ceectest";
?>
```

Comment: I doubt what you posted for code caused this error.

Comment: Well the message indicates that the error occurs at line 14. At that line, I've got this code: `$connBD = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHote;dbname=$dbNom", $dbUtilisateur, $dbMotPasse, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));`

Comment: Line number errors don't always mean it's on that line. *You've got to "read between the lines"* ;) my guess is that you're missing a bracket elsewhere, as the message states.

Comment: The error might state line 14 but the problem is above that. Post the rest of your code please

Comment: It's probably the hyphen in `ceec-wamp2008` that's causing havoc. Hyphens do funny things in SQL.

Comment: Maybe I should add. This is a part of code I had in a past project and it worked. Now I added it to my new project and it doesn't work. I can't explain it.

Comment: It's something else then, something you're not showing us.

Comment: Well you do have one '=>' on @ProgProsecutor spotted line I would start there if I were you

Comment: Tested the code, works fine, even with hyphen in the name. But neither of the files you've posted are 14 lines long, so you are leaving stuff out in your post

Comment: @Sebastien `T_DOUBLE_ARROW` doesn't have any relation to `=>` - Error is `Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting '('` - missing bracket somewhere.

Comment: @rjdown Of course, I have some commented lines  and the html tag.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well what is an T_DOUBLE_ARROW than? I would check you have two ')' at the end of this line maybe your missing a '(' somewhere check in case you commented it out.

Comment: T_DOUBLE_ARROW is a => but as Fred said, it's not the issue, it just happens to be the thing that made PHP realise something else is broken.

Comment: @ProgProsecutor so post it? Clearly a problem with it

Comment: @Sebastien `T_DOUBLE_ARROW` is an error that can be caused by anything, but clearly not by what OP posted for code; I can assure you of that.

Comment: You've got your connection in `<head></head>`?!

Comment: @Fred -ii- I tried it, it doesn't change anything, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Last ditch effort. Change `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">` to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and get rid of closing `?>` tags in `.php` files if nothing else follows. Those are all `.php` right?

Comment: Plus, you shouldn't be placing DB connection inside `<head></head>`. See if the above helped. Your DB stuff should be above HTML.

Comment: Yes, php file. I moved my connection to my body, like I should have done, and I didn't post it, but I do have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning. And no, still not working. Thanks for all your suggestions, I learnt a few new things. I think I'm just going to do it old school with mysql_connect.

Comment: You're not mixing in any `mysql_` or `mysqli_` anywhere, are you? Plus, is that your full code? No queries at all? Plus, try getting rid of `, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")` see if that works or not.

Comment: I started with mysql_ but I wanted to change for PDO. All my request I have are commented, so I figured it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Did you tried without the last option parameter : `$connBD = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHote;dbname=$dbNom", $dbUtilisateur, $dbMotPasse);` ?

Comment: I for one were unable to reproduce the error, even with the code you've supplied. If you're querying and you're not showing it, then that could be it. Other than that, I have no more suggestions.

Comment: I have now, but I now get a new error: `Parse error: parse error, unexpected ',', expecting '(' on line 20` the line of `$connBD -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );`.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Thanks a lot for your help, it may be a mistake from my part that I'm not seeing. It may be `ceec-wamp2008` like you suggested earlier...

Comment: Did you get the error if you just try with : `<?php
require ("Include/param_bd.inc");
$connBD = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHote;dbname=$dbNom", $dbUtilisateur, $dbMotPasse, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$connBD -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
?>` ... or even without `require ("Include/param_bd.inc");`...

Comment: Even without the require (the same error appears). Which is interesting... `ceec-wamp2008` may not be the problem after all.

Comment: So you have a 2 lines PHP file ($connBD = new and $connBD -> setAttribute) and you still have the error ?

Comment: Exactly. I'm going to check my php config file.

Comment: Merci Fabien. I don't have access to php.ini, but I have strong beliefs that this line lies there: `;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`. Maybe that's why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct solution but worth a try:

```
$connBD = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHote;dbname=$dbNom", $dbUtilisateur, $dbMotPasse, 
                  array(
                      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
                      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION 
                  )
        );
```

or without the double arrow at all:

```
$connBD = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHote;dbname=$dbNom", $dbUtilisateur, $dbMotPasse);
$connBD->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES utf8");
$connBD->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Comment: If I were you I would also try with the connection string harcoded it and if you still face trouble, strip everything out and keep just that piece of code